# A successful Post create via LinkedIn API cannot be read back

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a very simple cycle, I make a Post to a user's feed via the Share API and then I attempt to read back that post.

**Step 1: Share** ([using the Share API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api))

Send a POST request to the sharing endpoint: `/v1/people/~/shares`.

POST succeeds and I get a return value like the following.

```
<update>
  <update-key>UPDATE-1234-6789-SHARE</update-key>
  <update-url>https://www.linkedin.com/updates?discuss=&amp;scope=8219502&amp;stype=M&amp;topic=5705061301949063168&amp;type=U&amp;a=aovi</update-url>
</update>
```

**Step 2: Read back** ([using the Network Updates API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/get-network-updates-and-statistics-api))

Try to read the post specifically: `/v1/people/~/network/updates/key=UPDATE-1234-6789-SHARE`.

The return value I get is something like this:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "The update mapping to user's update-key cannot be processed.",
  "requestId": "0268X9ZRL7",
  "status": 400,
  "timestamp": 1418425769754
}
```

**Timing is important**. Running the same query 20 minutes later *generally* works as expected.

I have also tried just looking at the User's whole Feed `/v1/people/~/network/updates?scope=self`. In that case, the entry I seek is just missing.

- Is this a known LinkedIn issue? (*ticket #?*)
- If so, what type of delay does LinkedIn promise/expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're making the second API call to fetch the update with the same access token as the first API call, there shouldn't be more than a few seconds of delay expected. The POST call to create a new share asynchronously generates an Update-Key for you while the share gets processed in our system, but as I said it's within 1-3 seconds. I just tried these calls in sequence with a test share and was able to fetch the update as soon as I posted it. Is this a behavior you're consistently seeing?

Comment: _Are we seeing this consistently?_ Absolutely thousands of times per day. 

_The POST call to create a new share asynchronously generates an Update-Key for you while the share gets processed in our system, but as I said it's within 1-3 seconds._ 

We don't wait 3+ seconds, we check within milliseconds of the first call. However, it's not really listed in the docs that the delay is expected behaviour or what this delay _should_ be. We have personally seen delays of an hour+.

Comment: Clearly, I need to add a "wait" on my side, I understand that, I'm just trying to pin down how long that wait should be? Say to catch like 90%+ on the first try?

Comment: So I introduced a 3-second delay into my code back when this post was created. Based on running thousands of these calls daily, it is clear that the "delay" is well above 8 seconds. I understand that LinkedIn is undergoing a big API overhaul, is this the kind of performance we should expect going forward?

Answer (score 0):

I post an article via PC browser. And get update iva below api, it works.

```
/v1/people/~/network/updates?count=10&start=0&type=SHAR
```

SHAR: A connection has shared an update or link.

https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/get-network-updates-and-statistics-api